# longtable, landscape, and booktabs throw up errors in combination -- please help!

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, multirow, landscape, booktabs

I'm not really sure what my problem is, but I'll do my best to explain. I've been trying to put together a large, landscaped table summarizing some data. It all comes from a similar kind of source, so I'd like to keep it all in one table if I could. However, it's running over two pages. So I tried to switch to the longtable environment, and this caused the whole thing to break down. It gives me about 50 "Undefined control sequence" errors.

Any help is very welcome.

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \centering % Center table
        \ra{1.2}
        %\captionof{table}{Varieties of Schooling in the Towns, 1834-40}% Add 'table' caption
        \scalebox{1}{
        \begin{longtable}{@{} rcrrrrrrcrrcrr @{}}
            \caption{Summary of School Provision from Statistical Societies, 1834-40.\label{long}}\\

            \toprule[0.8mm]
            & \phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Day Scholars} & \phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sunday Scholars} & \phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Totals} \\
            \cmidrule{3-8}\cmidrule{10-11}\cmidrule{13-14}
            & \phantom{abc} & Dame & Common & Superior & Infant & Public & \% Under 5 &  & Total & \% Bi-enrolled & \phantom{abc} & Scholars & 1831 Pop.  \\ \midrule
            \endhead

            \bottomrule[0.8mm]
            \endfoot

            \textit{Manchester (1834)} \\
            M && 1,939 & 4,107 & 1,350 & 345 & 2,481 & \multirow{2}{*}{---} && 16,303 & \multirow{2}{*}{30\%} && 21,634 & 88,661\\
            F && 2,783 & 2,795 & 1,579 & 304 & 973 &&& 16,893                   &&&20,259&98,361\\
            \textit{Pendleton (1835)} \\
            M && 69 & 93 & 15 & 20 & 280 & \multirow{2}{*}{15\%} && 814 & \multirow{2}{*}{53\%} && 860 & 4023\\
            F && 159 & 131 & 72 & 45 & 273 &&& 872                  &&&1,090&4412\\
            \textit{Liverpool (1835)} \\
            M && 2,168 & 3,421 & 2,111 & 1,118 & 6,582 & \multirow{2}{*}{14\%} && 8,188 & \multirow{2}{*}{76\%} && 15,465& 76,626 \\
            F && 3,072 & 2,675 & 1,969 & 1,087 & 4,713 &&& 7,250                    &&&15,256 &88,549\\
            \textit{Bury (1835)} \\
            M && 258 & 535 & 51 & 137 & 272 & \multirow{2}{*}{20\%} && 1,899 & \multirow{2}{*}{27\%} && 2,639 &7,439 \\
            F && 582 & 273 & 123 & 106 & 137 &&& 2,325                  &&&2,918&7,647\\
            \textit{Salford (1835)} \\
            M && 563 & 1215 & 382 & 170 & 715 & \multirow{2}{*}{14\%} && 4826 & \multirow{2}{*}{35\%} && 6,182 & 24,212 \\
            F && 980 & 599 & 500 & 203 & 688 &&& 4928                   &&&6,173 & 26,598\\
            \textit{York (1836)} \\
            M && 270 & 300 & 264 & 205 & 1,155 & \multirow{2}{*}{13\%} && 1,722 & \multirow{2}{*}{75\%} && 2,625 & 11,989 \\
            F && 475 & 249 & 452 & 211 & 1,126 &&& 1,641                    &&&2,923&14,271\\
            \textit{Westminster (1837)} \\
            M && 125 & 402 & 475 & 362 & 633 & \multirow{2}{*}{22\%} && 573 & \multirow{2}{*}{57\%} && 2,243&20,781 \\
            F && 215 & 382 & 557 & 298 & 568 &&& 982                    &&& 2,442& 22,215\\
            \textit{Rutland (1838)} \\
            M && 277 & 272 & 85 & 0 & 941 & \multirow{2}{*}{16\%} && 1,650 & \multirow{2}{*}{60\%} && 2,235& 9,721 \\
            F && 401 & 268 & 51 & 0 & 669 &&& 1,546                     &&& 2,007& 9,664\\
            \textit{Kingston-upon-Hull (1839)} \\
            M/F && \multicolumn{5}{c}{--------------------- 8,988 ---------------------} & 11\% && 6,800 & 95\% && 9,328 & 32,958 \\
            \textit{Bristol (1840)} \\
            M && 1,357 & 1,679 & 510 & 1,004 & 2,741 & \multirow{2}{*}{22\%} && 5,780 & \multirow{2}{*}{37\%} && 10,932 & 46,535 \\
            F && 1,658 & 1,800 & 230 & 701 & 2,180 &&& 5,904                    &&& 10,289 & 57,351\\
            \textit{Birmingham (1840)} \\
            M && 1,829 & 2,007 & 989 & 471 & 2,100 & \multirow{2}{*}{20\%} && 9,284 & \multirow{2}{*}{25\%} && 14,359 & 71,756 \\
            F && 2,071 & 2,273 & 1,177 & 332 & 1,231 &&& 7,473                  &&& 12,690 & 75,230\\
        \end{longtable}}
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}
```

This is what it's supposed to look like, except this is more scrunched up than I'd like and leaves no room for citations:[image: Rendering of LaTeX pdf]

Again, any and all help would be very welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please do tell us which document class you employ and how wide the textblock is supposed to be.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I'm using this document class: https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/members/it/faqs/latex/thesis-class

And I'm not sure what you mean by the  width of the textblock. I think it's 6 inches. I found this in the class file:
`\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}`

Comment: Since you mention having no room for citations: Where would you like to add them? Which citation style would you like to use? A numeric citation style requires a lot less space than an author-year like style.

Comment: it is bad style to scale _any_ table but it can not work at all in a longtable `\scalebox{1}{\begin{longtable` `\scalebox` is like `\mbox` and makes a single line unbreakable box so breaks almost every aspect of longtable.  but `\scalebox{1}`  would never do anything useful anyway as no scaling is applied so it is just like `\mbox` but slower.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of your table is quite complicated, in no small part because it has three [3!] columns that are entirely empty and hence serve little more than to create code clutter. I'd get rid of the all-empty columns to simplify matters.

I'd also use a column type for the 10 data columns that performs alignment on the (explicit or implicit) decimal marker. The `S` column type can do this job; it can also handle the task of inserting `,` ("comma") as the thousands-separator.

The following screenshot shows the first 15 or so rows of the table that results from adopting the aforementioned suggestions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{ociamthesis}
  % paper size: a4paper
  % width and height of text block: 6.0" and 9.0"

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\sisetup{group-separator={,},group-four-digits}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{\clearpage% 
    %\thispagestyle{empty} % I wouldn't do this
    \begin{landscape}

    %\ra{1.2} % better to use selective spacing via '\addlinespace' (see below)
    \setlength\LTcapwidth\textwidth
    \begin{longtable}{@{} r *{5}{T{4.0}} c T{5.0} c T{5.0}T{5.0} @{}}
    \caption{Summary of School Provision from Statistical 
         Societies, 1834--40.}\label{long}\\
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Day Scholars}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sunday Scholars}   
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Totals} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(l){10-11}
    & \mc{Dame} & \mc{Common} & \mc{Superior} & \mc{Infant} 
    & \mc{Public} & \mc{\% Under 5} & \mc{Total} 
    & \mc{\% Bi-enrolled} & \mc{Scholars} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{1831 Pop.} \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, cont'd from previous page}\\
    \addlinespace  
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Day Scholars}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sunday Scholars}   
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Totals} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(l){10-11}
    & \mc{Dame} & \mc{Common} & \mc{Superior} & \mc{Infant} 
    & \mc{Public} & \mc{\% Under 5} & \mc{Total} 
    & \mc{\% Bi-enrolled} & \mc{Scholars} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{1831 Pop.} \\ 
    \midrule  
    \endhead

    \midrule
    \multicolumn{11}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on following page)}
    \endfoot

    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

    %% body of longtable
    \textit{Manchester (1834)} \\
    M & 1939 & 4107 & 1350 & 345 & 2481 & \multirow{2}{*}{---} 
    & 16303 & \multirow{2}{*}{30\%} 
    & 21634 & 88661\\
    F & 2783 & 2795 & 1579 & 304 & 973 & & 16893
    & & 20259 & 98361\\
    \addlinespace
    \textit{Pendleton (1835)} \\
    M & 69 & 93 & 15 & 20 & 280 & \multirow{2}{*}{15\%} & 814 & \multirow{2}{*}{53\%} & 860 & 4023\\
    F & 159 & 131 & 72 & 45 & 273 && 872          &&1090&4412\\
    \addlinespace
    \textit{Liverpool (1835)} \\
    M & 2168 & 3421 & 2111 & 1118 & 6582 & \multirow{2}{*}{14\%} & 8188 & \multirow{2}{*}{76\%} & 15465& 76626 \\
    F & 3072 & 2675 & 1969 & 1087 & 4713 && 7250 &&15256 &88549\\
    \addlinespace
    \textit{Bury (1835)} \\
    M & 258 & 535 & 51 & 137 & 272 & \multirow{2}{*}{20\%} & 1899 & \multirow{2}{*}{27\%} & 2639 &7439 \\
    F & 582 & 273 & 123 & 106 & 137 && 2325 &&2918&7647\\
    \addlinespace
    \textit{Salford (1835)} \\
    M & 563 & 1215 & 382 & 170 & 715 & \multirow{2}{*}{14\%} & 4826 & \multirow{2}{*}{35\%} & 6182 & 24212 \\
    F & 980 & 599 & 500 & 203 & 688 && 4928&&6173 & 26598\\
    \addlinespace
    \textit{York (1836)} \\
    M & 270 & 300 & 264 & 205 & 1155 & \multirow{2}{*}{13\%} & 1722 & \multirow{2}{*}{75\%} & 2625 & 11989 \\
    F & 475 & 249 & 452 & 211 & 1126 && 1641 &&2923&14271\\
    \addlinespace
    \textit{Westminster (1837)} \\
    M & 125 & 402 & 475 & 362 & 633 & \multirow{2}{*}{22\%} & 573 & \multirow{2}{*}{57\%} & 2243&20781 \\
    F & 215 & 382 & 557 & 298 & 568 && 982 && 2442& 22215\\
    %\addlinespace
    \pagebreak
    \textit{Rutland (1838)} \\
    M & 277 & 272 & 85 & 0 & 941 & \multirow{2}{*}{16\%} & 1650 & \multirow{2}{*}{60\%} & 2235& 9721 \\
    F & 401 & 268 & 51 & 0 & 669 && 1546  && 2007& 9664\\
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\textit{Kingston-upon-Hull (1839)}} \\
    M\&F & \multicolumn{5}{c}{------------------------ 8{,}988 ------------------------} & 11\% & 6800 & 95\% & 9328 & 32958 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textit{Bristol (1840)} \\
    M & 1357 & 1679 & 510 & 1004 & 2741 & \multirow{2}{*}{22\%} & 5780 & \multirow{2}{*}{37\%} & 10932 & 46535 \\
    F & 1658 & 1800 & 230 & 701 & 2180 && 5904 && 10289 & 57351\\
    \addlinespace
    \textit{Birmingham (1840)} \\
    M & 1829 & 2007 & 989 & 471 & 2100 & \multirow{2}{*}{20\%} & 9284 & \multirow{2}{*}{25\%} & 14359 & 71756 \\
    F & 2071 & 2273 & 1177 & 332 & 1231 && 7473 && 12690 & 75230\\
    \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
}
\end{document}
```